# Styling Telerik WPF NumericUpDown Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik, numericupdown, wpf-style

I use Telerik WPF controls and need to add a NumericUpDown control to my UI. The thing is when used "as it is" it doesn't fit the rest of the application visually

`<TL;DR>
This is a bigger application, that's not been written fully by me. Other people somehow managed to "import" other telerik controls and assign them other styles. Sadly, nobody's used the UpDown control before.
</>`

I added the control to my UI:

```
<telerik:RadNumericUpDown
  Minimum="0"
  Maximum="10"
  SmallChange="1"
  NumberDecimalDigits="0"
  IsInteger="True"
  Value="{Binding Path=Counter}" />
```

Also, I've added some styling to a ResourceDictionary:

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerikInput:RadNumericUpDown}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Border.CornerRadius" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Border.BorderThickness" Value="1" />
  </Style>
```

And this handles some basic styling features (border, margin, etc). In general it looks "good enough". There's only one problem - when a mouse pointer hovers over the control, it becomes shiny and glossy. That's not like my other controls behave - is there an easy way to remove this effect ?

I've tried experimenting with Triggers:

```
<Style>
...
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
      <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
      ...
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But this didn't do much. I've also tried setting IncreaseButtonContentTemplate field, but this turned out no good either.

Comment: Try with `<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the default `ControlTemplates` and remove any "shiny and glossy" effects from them. The easiest way to do this would be to copy the default templates from the `Themes.Implicit` folder in your Telerik installation directory into your solution and then edit them as per your requirements.

There is no "DisableEffects" property that you can simply set on the control I am afraid.

Comment: OK, so looks like I won't getaway with reimplementing the style from scratch. Thanks a lot.

Pfeeeew.... that's gonna be fun... ;)